# ¿Como resolver un problema sobre POO y recursividad /Expected method 'sacar_dinero' to be defined as: def sacar_dinero(alcancia, monto):?

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, funciones, recursión

> Hola, estoy tratando de resolver este problema de alcancías. Tengo
> problemas con la funcion que me pide crear y luego para llamarla así
> misma dentro de la Clase Alcancía. El ejercicio dice lo siguiente:
>
> Está definida la siguiente clase Alcancia:

```
class Alcancia:
    def __init__(self, nombre, dinero, alcancia):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.dinero = dinero
        self.siguiente_alcancia = alcancia
```

> Cada alcancía tiene un nombre que es un string que guarda una
> descripción del tipo de alcancía, un entero dinero con la cantidad de
> dinero almacenado en la alcancía y una alcancía siguiente_alcancia, la
> cuál es la siguiente alcancía de la cuál vas a sacar dinero si se
> acaba el de la alcancía actual.
>
> Por ejemplo, si tienes las siguientes alcancías:

```
a1 = Alcancia('Chanchito de greda', 900, None)
a2 = Alcancia('Debajo del Colchón', 100, a1)
```

> Entonces si intentas quitar 300 de la alcancía a2 deberás quitar los
> 100 que le quedan y luego 200 de la alcancía a1.
>
> Notar que la alcancía a1 no tiene una siguiente_alcancia (ya que
> siguiente_alcancia = None). Puedes suponer que nunca se pedirá sacar
> más dinero del que contiene una alcancía cuya siguiente alcancía sea
> None.
>
> Para este ejercicio deberás definir la función recursiva
> sacar_dinero(alcancia, monto). La función deberá restar el monto de la
> alcancía indicada. Si el dinero en la alcancía no alcanza para el
> monto que se necesita, entonces deberás ir a la siguiente alcancía y
> sacar el resto. Deberás repetir lo anterior hasta haber restado tanto
> dinero entre todas las alcancías como el monto indicado.
>
> Nota: el corrector de este ejercicio siempre tendrá la alcancía a1 con
> siguiente_alcancia = None, la alcancía a2 con siguiente_alcancía = a1,
> la alcancía a3 con siguiente_alcancia = a2 y así.

```
class Alcancia:    
    def __init__(self, nombre, dinero, alcancia):        
        self.nombre = nombre        
        self.dinero = dinero        
        self.siguiente_alcancia = alcancia    

    def sacar_dinero(self, alcancia, monto):        
        if alcancia.dinero >= monto:        
            alcancia.dinero -= monto
            return True
        elif alcancia.siguiente_alcancia is not None: 
            monto_restante = monto - alcancia.dinero
            alcancia.dinero = 0 
            return self.siguiente_alcancia.sacar_dinero(alcancia.siguiente_alcancia, monto_restante)
         else:
            return False

a1 = Alcancia('Chanchito de greda', 900, None)
a2 = Alcancia('Debajo del Colchón', 100, a1)
```

> Finalmente definiendo sacar_dinero por fuera de class Alcancía era lo
> que me pedían como correcto , aunque funcionaba de todas maneras.
> Acá el código:

```
class Alcancia:    
    def __init__( self, nombre, dinero, alcancia ):        
        self.nombre = nombre        
        self.dinero = dinero        
        self.siguiente_alcancia = alcancia    

def sacar_dinero( alcancia, monto):
        if alcancia.dinero>= monto:
            alcancia.dinero -= monto
            return True
        elif alcancia.siguiente_alcancia is not None:
            monto_restante = monto - alcancia.dinero
            alcancia.dinero = 0
            return sacar_dinero(alcancia.siguiente_alcancia, monto_restante)
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Alcancia:    
    def __init__( self, nombre, dinero, alcancia ):        
        self.nombre = nombre        
        self.dinero = dinero        
        self.siguiente_alcancia = alcancia    

       # acá quité el parámetro alcancia, ya que vamos a 
       # llamar al método así: "alcancia.sacar_dinero( 10 )
    def sacar_dinero( self, monto ):    

           # consecuencia del cambio anterior, cambiamos "alcancia" por "self"    
        if self.dinero >= monto:        
            self.dinero -= monto
            return True
        elif self.siguiente_alcancia is not None: 
            monto_restante = monto - self.dinero
            self.dinero = 0 
            return self.siguiente_alcancia.sacar_dinero( monto_restante )
        else:
            return False

a1 = Alcancia('Chanchito de greda', 900, None)
a2 = Alcancia('Debajo del Colchón', 100, a1)

print( a2.sacar_dinero( 110 ))  # imprime "true"
print( a2.sacar_dinero( 1100 )) # imprime "false"
```

La POO, es difícil, cuando logras entenderla, es la gloria, no todos lo logran... tu profe entre ellos.

```
class Alcancia:    
    def __init__( self, nombre, dinero, alcancia ):        
        self.nombre = nombre        
        self.dinero = dinero        
        self.siguiente_alcancia = alcancia    

    def sacar_dinero( self, alcancia, monto ):    
        if alcancia.dinero >= monto:        
            alcancia.dinero -= monto
            return True
        elif alcancia.siguiente_alcancia is not None: 
            monto_restante = monto - alcancia.dinero
            alcancia.dinero = 0 
            return alcancia.sacar_dinero( alcancia.siguiente_alcancia, monto_restante )
        else:
            return False

a1 = Alcancia( 'Chanchito de greda', 900, None )
a2 = Alcancia( 'Debajo del Colchón', 100, a1 )

print( a2.sacar_dinero( a2, 111 ))  # imprime "true"
print( a2.sacar_dinero( a2, 1111 )) # imprime "false"
```

Lo que acabo de hacer, es una "chanchada", como verás en la ridícula  llamada al método **sacar_dinero**, que quedo así:

```
 a2.sacar_dinero( a2, 111 )
```

osea, llamo al método de **a2** y le paso como parámetro **a2**, la forma correcta de hacerlo, es la anterior, obviamente, esto no se lo digas al profe, a menos que quieras reprobar!!!, lo importante es que tu lo entiendas, un objeto tiene atributos y métodos, y es mediante el, que se los invoca (hay excepciones, pero se haría muy largo, toma esto como una base).
Si te queda alguna duda, no dudes en preguntar.

Comment: Hola. Es interesante ver que también así funciona , pero el corrector sigue diciendo: INCORRECTO Expected method 'sacar_dinero' to be defined as:
def sacar_dinero(alcancia, monto):
Pareciera que el def sacar_dinero  debería mantenerse sin modificar. No se si es que hay que hacerlo no como un método de Alcancia , si no por fuera, pienso . Pero no me estaría saliendo.

Comment: Finalmente puede resolver lo que me pedían.  El ejercicio se resolvía realizando la función por fuera de class Alcancía. Voy a agregar  el código a continuación de mi pregunta inicial.

Comment: Grande maestro!!.